# How to describe strings ending with one or two numbers in one LIKE pattern?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I am searching for a string ending with one or two numbers, I am using the following pattern:

```
WHERE MyString LIKE 'ABC[0-9]'
OR MyString LIKE 'ABC[0-9][0-9]'
```

Is there a way to express my intent in one single equivalent pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `LIKE` supported regex quantifier syntax, you *would* do:

```
LIKE 'ABC[0-9]{1,2}'
```

However, according to [the spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) it does not.

If you do not want to use the regular expression functions, then you are stuck with what you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expressions with SQLServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx).

Then your expression will become something like:

```
where dbo.RegexMatch( MyString, N'^ABC[0-9]{1,2}$' )
```

Comment: @Allon Guralnek: if the prototype survives the first few months, we might be migrating the whole thing, possibly to PostreSQL. So CLR makes little sense.

Comment: @ArneLund: That's pertinent information that should be mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

One way, although there is not much wrong with the 2 `ORs` (Remove `'??' +` to skip values that are *just* 1 or 2 digits)

```
;with T(f) as (
    select 'xxxxxxxxx' union
    select 'xxxxxxxx6' union
    select 'xxxxxxx66' union
    select 'xxxxxx666' union
    select 'xxxxx6666' union 
    select 'xxxxx666x' union
    select '66' union
    select '6' union
    select ''
)
select 
    *
from 
    T
where 
    patindex('%[^0-9]%', reverse(right('??' + f, 3))) > 1

>>

f
6
66
xxxxxxx66
xxxxxxxx6
```

Comment: This is not simple, but I liked the idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(MyString, 4, 2) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```