# Find records with digits in text by regex in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, regex

I am going to find records that contain the following text in a column:

1. Clone of my item
2. Clone1 of my item
3. Clone2 of my item
4. Clone10 of my item
5. Clone15 of my item

There is always a number after the 'Copy' word.

Does it possible to get them by a single query? I've found a solution by using 'union' only.

```
select * from items where name like 'Clone of my item'
union
select * from items where name like 'Clone% of my item'
union
select * from items where name like 'Clone%% of my item'
```

But I don't like it because if I want to find something like 'Copy123 of my item' then I have to edit the query above just to add one more union with 3 '%' characters

```
select * from items where name like 'Clone%%% of my item'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to describe strings ending with one or two numbers in one LIKE pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478775/how-to-describe-strings-ending-with-one-or-two-numbers-in-one-like-pattern)

Comment: Your question says "copy" your SQL say `Clone`. Which is it? SQL Server however, has no native support for Regex,

Comment: @Larnu Yes, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Single **Wildcard %** is enough to achieve this

```
DECLARE @T Table(Col Varchar(max))

insert into @T Values('Copy of my item')
insert into @T Values('Copy1 of my item' )
insert into @T Values('Copy2 of my item' )
insert into @T Values('Copy10 of my item')
insert into @T Values('Copy150000 of my item')


select * from @T 
where col like 'Copy% of my item'
```

[image]

Comment: What is the use of `%` here if you get all the results the same as it is?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

Here the first part is to find the first word from the sentence using the below query:

```
LEFT(ColA, (PATINDEX('% %', ColA)))
```

Here `colA` is the name of the column. Then find the number from that first word using the function `TRY_CONVERT()`.

```
create table Test (ColA varchar(150))
insert into Test values
('Copy of my item'),
('Copy1 of my item'),
('Copy2 of my item'),
('Copy10 of my item'),
('Copy15 of my item')

--Original Query
SELECT ColA
    ,LEFT(ColA, (PATINDEX('% %', ColA))) AS FirstWord
    ,TRY_CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(LEFT(ColA, (PATINDEX('% %', ColA))), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', LEFT(ColA, (PATINDEX('% %', ColA)))), LEN(LEFT(ColA, (PATINDEX('% %', ColA)))))) AS NumberPart
FROM Test;

--Final Query
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT ColA
        ,LEFT(ColA, (PATINDEX('% %', ColA))) AS FirstWord
        ,TRY_CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(LEFT(ColA, (PATINDEX('% %', ColA))), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', LEFT(ColA, (PATINDEX('% %', ColA)))), LEN(LEFT(ColA, (PATINDEX('% %', ColA)))))) AS NumberPart
    FROM Test
    )
SELECT ColA
FROM cte
WHERE Isnull(NumberPart, 0) > 0
```

You can either avoid where condition if you want the result with not any numbers.

On the other hand you can put where condition as shown below for the word with two-digit numbers containing. You can also use the other operators like `(<, >, =, <= or >=, etc).`

```
WHERE Isnull(NumberPart, 0) > 9
```

[Db<>Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c23c1978159e3ded03a88111adc189b5)